# Obtain text from lxml Comment

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to get the content of the `_Comment`. I've researched quite a bit on how do do it, but I don't know how to access the function from the `td` element in order to grab the text. I'm using xpaths with the python Scrapy module if that helps.

```
td = None [_Element]
    <built-in function Comment> = None [_Comment]
    a = None [_Element]
```

The HTML for the `td` element is:

```
<table class="crIFrameReviewList">

    <tr>
      <td>

<!-- BOUNDARY -->
<a name="R2L4AFEICL8GG6"></a><br />


<div style="margin-left:0.5em;">

      <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
        304 of 309 people found the following review helpful
      </div>
      <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
        <span style='margin-left: -5px;'><img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/customer-reviews/stars-5-0._V192240867_.gif" width="64" alt="5.0 out of 5 stars" title="5.0 out of 5 stars" height="12" border="0" /> </span>
        <b>Great Travel Zoom</b>, <nobr>April 9, 2014</nobr>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">

      <div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
        <span class="crVerifiedStripe"><b class="h3color tiny" style="margin-right: 0.5em;">Verified Purchase</b><span class="tiny verifyWhatsThis">(<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/community-help/amazon-verified-purchase" target="AmazonHelp" onclick="amz_js_PopWin('http://www.amazon.com/gp/community-help/amazon-verified-purchase', 'AmazonHelp', 'width=400,height=500,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,status=1');return false; ">What's this?</a>)</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
        <b><span class="h3color tiny">This review is from: </span>Canon PowerShot SX700 HS Digital Camera (Black) (Electronics)</b>
      </div>

For the recent few years Canon has made great efforts to improve their travel-zoom compact cameras, and the new SX700 is their next remarkable achievement on that way. It's a little bit bigger than its predecessor (SX280) but it is very well built and has an attractive look and feel (I like the black one). It also got a new front grip which makes one-hand shooting more convenient, even when shooting video, since the Video button was moved from the back to the top and you can now use your thumb solely for holding the camera.<br /><br />Here is a brief list of the new camera pros & cons:<br /><br />PROS:<br />* A very good design and build quality with the attractive finish.<br />* A new powerful 30x optical zoom lens in just a pocket-size body.<br />* Incredible range from 25mm wide to 750mm telephoto for stills and video.<br />* Zoom Framing Assist - very useful new feature to compose your pictures at long telephoto.<br />* Very effective optical Intelligent Image Stabilization for...


<a href="http://www.amazon.com/Canon-PowerShot-SX700-Digital-Camera/product-reviews/B00I58M26Y" target="_top">Read more</a>
      <div style="padding-top: 10px; clear: both; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Can you show an actual HTML you are dealing with? Also, the desired output would help.

Comment: @alecxe I updated it with the edit. I have converted the html to an  lxml.etree.HTML object

Comment: Are there multiple `div` elements with `class="reviewText"`? Otherwise you can use `'//div[@class="reviewText"]/text()'` as your `xpath`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `div` with `class="reviewText"` using `.//div[@class="reviewText"]` xpath expression and dump the element to string using `tostring()` with a `text` method:

```
import lxml.html

data = """
your html here
"""

td = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
review = td.find('.//div[@class="reviewText"]')
print lxml.html.tostring(review, method="text")
```

Prints:

```
54,000 RPM - It has a spinning disk drive that is way beyond our time...I bought 10 of these just for the hard drive, they blow SSD's out of the water.
Seriously though... how does a well known computer company mistype an important spec?
```

Comment: I edited it to have what is given to me from Amazon. They implement anti-scraping techniques for their site and though I would consider myself decently experienced in xpaths, this one is befuddling me. The closest I've gotten to the answer is the `<built in function Comment>`. If only I could access it.

Comment: @robert ok, could you add the current code you have for me to start with? Thanks.